# jQuery code and role button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make up a jquery code which will push a "button" which is actually a ' role="button" ' 
code on a website.
I am trying this code in Chrome but nothing happens. Any idea?

```
var button = $('[role="button"]');

  button.click();
```

Comment: And what should happen?

Comment: Does the button have an event handler attached to it? If nothing is happening then it is quite likely it does not. Also, your code will trigger the `click` event on *all* `[role="button"]` elements on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rbroden/buu8140c/

I have created a simple jsfiddle that accomplishes what you are trying to do. I think.

HTML

```
<button role="button">Button</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$('[role=button]').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```